# how to convert Json<T<'_>> to object with rocket.rs?

Tags: json, rust, rust-rocket

I learning this Todo List example: https://github.com/letsgetrusty/rsty-stack-example.

https://github.com/letsgetrusty/rsty-stack-example/blob/main/todo_api/src/main.rs#L20 - place in code that I trying to change.

I want to be able send POST request in JSON content type with JSON data inside http body, parse it and use as Task Struct Object.

Now, I got this:

```rust
use rocket::serde::{Deserialize, json::Json};

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(crate = "rocket::serde")]
struct Task<'r> {
    title: &'r str,
    description: &'r str,
    complete: bool,
    warning_at: &'r str,
}

#[post("/task/new", data = "<task>")]
async fn add_task(task: Json<Task<'_>>, db: &State<DB>) {
    let task = db
        .add_task(task) // How to send task as object
        .await
        .map_err(|_| std::io::Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Unable to create task."))?;

    Ok(Json(task))
}
```

This topic is only about this line of code. I know that `db.add_task()` have wrong arguments, Im not yet there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### 1. Using `Json::into_inner` method

You can consume Rocket's [`Json`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/serde/json/struct.Json.html#) wrapper type with its [`into_inner`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/serde/json/struct.Json.html#method.into_inner) method, converting `Json<Task>` to `Task`, so `.add_task(task.into_inner())` should probably work (if `add_task` takes a `Task` object as input):

```
#[post("/task/new", data = "<task>")]
async fn add_task(task: Json<Task<'_>>, db: &State<DB>) {
    let task = db
        .add_task(task.into_inner())
        .await
        .map_err(|_| std::io::Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Unable to create task."))?;

    Ok(Json(task))
}
```

##### 2. Using the inner value directly

Alternatively, since `Json` is a [tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#using-tuple-structs-without-named-fields-to-create-different-types) which exposes the wrapped type publicly, instead of `into_inner` you could also use the exposed field directly with `task.0`:

```
#[post("/task/new", data = "<task>")]
async fn add_task(task: Json<Task<'_>>, db: &State<DB>) {
    let task = db
        .add_task(task.0)
        .await
        .map_err(|_| std::io::Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Unable to create task."))?;

    Ok(Json(task))
}
```

##### 3. Using pattern destructuring

Lastly, you can [destructure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#destructuring) the `Json` directly in your argument, assigning your `task` binding to the wrapped/inner value of type `Task` instead of `Json<Task>`:

```
#[post("/task/new", data = "<task>")]
async fn add_task(Json(task): Json<Task<'_>>, db: &State<DB>) {
    let task = db
        .add_task(task)
        .await
        .map_err(|_| std::io::Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Unable to create task."))?;

    Ok(Json(task))
}
```

Thanks to @Masklinn for pointing out the second and third option.

Comment: `Json`'s item is `pub` so as in Axum (where that's the standard way) you could use `Json(task): Json<Task<'_>>`. `task.0` should also do fine.

Comment: 3 Doesn't seem to work for me in rocket, I get the error: handler arguments must be of the form `ident: Type`